# Java symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11/lib/libnio.so: undefined symbol: initInetAddressIDs

Tags: java, shared-libraries, 64-bit, suse, undefined-symbol

I am using openjdk-11 in a suse linux server. When I try to run my cpp build with -64bit flag I am getting this error:

> Java symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11/lib/libnio.so: undefined symbol: initInetAddressIDs

Here is my ldd warning:

> you do not have execution permission for `/usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/libnio.so' linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff32bd7000) libjava.so => /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/libjava.so libnet.so => /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/libnet.so libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f73ee49e000) libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f73ee0e4000) libjvm.so => not found libverify.so => /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/libverify.so /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

I'm not a Java programmer and have no clue what to do here. Could someone please help me get out of this pit?

Comment: can u try running `ldd /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11/lib/libnio.so` and post the output ?

Comment: ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/libnio.so'
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff32bd7000)
        libjava.so => /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/libjava.so 
        libnet.so => /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/libnet.so
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f73ee49e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f73ee0e4000)
        libjvm.so => not found
        libverify.so => /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/libverify.so 
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Comment: @nullPointer Pasted the ldd output above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ldd output states that `libjvm.so` is missing.
Try to find this file in your OpenJDK path (try looking into `/jre/lib/amd64/server/` ), and then try adding this path to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Thanks a lot @nullPointer .. It worked. I just added libjvm.so to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It was in /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11/lib/server/libjvm.so path .. :)

Comment: thx for the reminder about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. In my case `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was all that was needed.