# Error trying to run a flutter app from the CLI (real device)

Tags: java, android, linux, flutter

I'm trying to configure my arch linux distro in order to develop and run Flutter applications (for android). My problem is that when I try to run:

```
flutter run -v
```

it give me this error:

> [+1614 ms] /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /opt/android-studio/jre/lib/libnio.so: undefined symbol: initInetAddressIDs

> [+2 ms] "flutter run" took 22,173ms.
> [  +10 ms]
> #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
> #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:687:9)
>
> #2      FlutterCommand.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1161:27)
>
> #3      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
>
> #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
>
> #6      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
>
> #8      run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
>
> #9      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)

I've search and try possible solutions. The most specific and related solution for a similar problem was add to my $LD_LIBRARY_PATH the path of /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so, but it didn't work (doesn't change nothing).
I also add to my $LD_LIBRARY_PATH this path "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/server/" but also it didn't work.
The link to this solution: [Java symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11/lib/libnio.so: undefined symbol: initInetAddressIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414619/java-symbol-lookup-error-usr-lib64-jvm-java-11-openjdk-11-lib-libnio-so-undef)

Another "solution" I try, was to run the app from Android Studio and it magically worked! That makes me feel even more worried because I don't understand why I can't run it from my CLI without have to open Android Studio (which consume more than half of my PC resources).

Important details:

- I have java-17-openjdk and java-8-openjdk. I'm currently using java-17-openjdk
- /opt/android-studio/ has a bin folder that contain a java-11 file. When I run an app from Android Studio it use the java-11 binary instead my java-17 (computer's default). This also appear when I ran an flutter app:

> ```
> [ +177 ms] Exit code 0 from: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
> [        ] openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
>            OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
>            OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822, mixed mode)
> ```

Could please someone helps me or even explain me why this is happening?

Comment: How did you install the SDK? I've also got it working on Ubuntu and use Visual Studio Code to run my app on the emulator and it's working great. I'd love to help you out.

Comment: I install it through yay (the sdk platform tools, command line tools, SDK build tools and the adb package), I'd follow the ArchWiki tutorial. Also, I find a quite dummy solution. I just installed java-11-openjdk and make it my default option. Since then, I haven't had any  problem with debugging and installing Flutter apps on my Android.