# Oracle SQL Developer is missing libjvm.so

Tags: java, shared-libraries, oracle-sqldeveloper, manjaro

I am trying to run `Oracle SQL Developer 22.2.1` under `Manjaro 22.0.1` using `openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17`. For debugging purposes, I have experimented with and yielded the same results using `openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17`. Both have been installed using `pacman`from the official arch repositories (`jre17-openjdk` and `jre11-openjdk` respectively).

This resulted in the following error:

```
> oracle-sqldeveloper
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libnio.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libnio.so: undefined symbol: reuseport_available
```

Inspecting `libnio.so` more closely, the culprit seems to actually be `libjvm.so`:

```
> ldd /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libnio.so                                                                                                                                                                         
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe0f1d7000)
        libjava.so => /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjava.so (0x00007f7354ce7000)
        libnet.so => /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libnet.so (0x00007f7354ccf000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7354abb000)
        /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7354d23000)
        libjvm.so => not found
        libjvm.so => not found
```

This is in turn located under `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so`. A bit of research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414619/java-symbol-lookup-error-usr-lib64-jvm-java-11-openjdk-11-lib-libnio-so-undef) and [there](https://anhqle.github.io/rstudio-cannot-load-rjava-in-ubuntu/) yields setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as a potential solution. And indeed, by doing so, the application starts just fine!

**Now finally on to my actual questions:**

- Is this some problem with my JDK installation and those links are supposed to work out-of-the-box?
- I am regularly working with 2-3 different JDK installations (openjdk and GraalVM 8, 11 and 17). How would I best set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for those different versions that each have their own `lib` directories?

Currently, I am only facing the problems with SQL Developer. I have already explicitly set the Java version to use in `~/.sqldeveloper/22.2.1/product.conf`. Maybe there would also be a possibility to supply the library path in there? Using `-Djava.library.path` did not work so far.

Comment: FYI the product is setup to be ran with Oracle JDK, and doesn't technically support OpenJDK.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I now tested the same with Oracle JDK 19. It was installed from the AUR (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jdk). It yields the same problem! The only difference is the undefined symbol is now `undefined symbol: ipv6_available`.

Comment: well we dont support 19 either, it's oracle java 11, that what we test for, and distribute for windows and macs

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thanks for the clarification! Unfortunately, it's exactly the same problem with Oracle JDK11. `jdk-11.0.17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` downloaded manually from oracle.com trying to reference `libjvm.so` that it can't locate in the `lib/server` directory without explicitly setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: do we know your java is a valid home? Can you for example start sqlcl (it's the sql.sh in your sqldeveloper/bin) directory. From a cmd prompt, just run sql /nolog . Then if that gets you a prompt, run 'show java' . Is it using the same home you think SQLDev is ?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith No, I cannot start it as my default jdk installation is openjdk8. This is required by my daily business and the reason that I've used `SetJavaHome` in `product.conf`. `JAVA_HOME` is not explicitly set. Is there anything else that you'd relate to "a valid home"?

Comment: we don't support openJDK, esp openJDK 8 - i would expect problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave my final solution here for reference in case anyone else also stumbles across that issue:

Oracle SQLDeveloper, at least on arch installations, also requires the [java11-openjfx](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/java11-openjfx/) package. The `PKGBUILD` file even says so and lists it as an optional dependency. So all that was left to do after installing that was to reference the proper (on my system non-default) JDK installation to use in the `product.conf`:

`SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-jdk`

Answer (score 1):

On my Manjaro installation, i've set the environment variables:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/default/lib/server`

I set the variables appointing to the `default` symlink, to appoint to default JVM set from the `archlinux-java` program. Before set this variables, the Oracle SQL Developer has opened normally.

---

From the .desktop file, other change is necessary. To do this, you can use the `menulibre` to edit the Oracle SQL Developer SQL Entry. In the command field (equivalent to the line which starts from `Exec=` text), change to the below line:

`env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/default/lib/server /usr/bin/oracle-sqldeveloper`

---

My solution is derived from the 'drslmr' solution to fix the Eclipse installation: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/eclipse-java#news

Answer (score 0):

As @thatjeffsmith has commented I would not expect SQLDeveloper to work 100% with OpenJDK (even if Oracle says so).

About your specific scenario the only answer I can think of is having scripts (think of catalina.sh or catalina.bat) to specify diferent locations for that specific environment variable (LD_LIBRARY_PATH). This is not a Java problem, but more a specific JNI problem, which needs to be solved under the JVM (as opposed to IN the JVM).

Comment: I now tested the same with Oracle JDK 19. It was installed from the AUR (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jdk). It yields the same problem! The only difference is the undefined symbol is now `undefined symbol: ipv6_available`.